# Curl works but not Python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to fetch a JSON response from http://erdos.sdslabs.co/users/shagun.json. Using browser/Python's [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library leads to an authentication error,  but curl seems to work fine.

```
curl http://erdos.sdslabs.co/users/shagun.json
```

returns the JSON response.

Why would the curl request work while a normal browser or Requests-based request fail?

Comment: are you at home or in a company network?

Comment: Visiting that url in a browser redirects me to a login dialog, but curl works. Perhaps it is checking the User-Agent?

Comment: In that case Requests should have worked.

Comment: you don’t have a proxy or anything set up, do you?

Comment: No. No proxy is set up

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use another library. Lost a LOT of time and never got it to work, switched lib and BOOM, working exactly as curl.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using telnet to check:

```
$ telnet erdos.sdslabs.co 80
Trying 62.141.37.215...
Connected to erdos.sdslabs.co.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET http://erdos.sdslabs.co/users/shagun.json HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 26 Jul 2014 11:18:58 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=juvg7vrg3vs4t00om3a95m4sc7; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: /login
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://erdos.sdslabs.co
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Content-Length: 1449
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

{"email":"sshagun.sodhani@gmail.com","username":"shagun","name":"Shagun      
[...]
```

We see that the web server is responding with a 302 - a redirection to Location /login. Requests and web browsers are obeying that, and reaching the login prompt. However, we see that the web server is *also* responding with the json you're after, and curl (and telnet) are simple enough to just accept that data.

Best practice would be to fix the web server so that it either doesn't require you to log in, or doesn't give out password-protected data at the same time as asking users to log in.

If you can't change the web server, you could tell the requests module to ignore redirects:

```
import requests
result = requests.get('http://erdos.sdslabs.co/users/shagun.json', allow_redirects=False)
print result.content
```

Answer (score 8):

For late googlers like myself:

In my case, the problem was that I provided url params using `requests.get(url, data={...})`. After changing it to `requests.get(url, params={...})`, the problem was solved.

Comment: This was exactly my case and now it works, thanks! I think I had changed back and forth between POST and GET and didn't realise they use different parameter names.

Answer (score 4):

In case you have a proxy configured at your environment, define it at your session/request as well.

For example with session:

```
    my_proxies = {  
        'http': 'http://myproxy:8080',  
        'https': 'https://myproxy:8080'  
    }

    session = requests.Session()  
    request = requests.Request('POST', 'http://my.domain.com', data=params_template, headers=req_headers, proxies=my_proxies)  
    prepped = session.prepare_request(request)  
    response = session.send(prepped)
```

see documentation:
request http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/
session http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: Hey @IsaacE Thanks for your answer. In this case, the issue was not because of proxy though :)

Comment: @IssacE check the accepted answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/24970508/1353861

Answer (score 3):

I had the experience that some python requests code that had worked previously  one day didn't come back the next, while curl was still working. It wasn't the code, and it wasn't the server, and reading this discussion it dawned on me that something in the connection may have changed. **I disabled and re-enabled my Wifi, and lo and behold, it worked again.**

I didn't investigate further, requests may have cached something that wasn't valid any more. Sorry about this unqualified input, but maybe it will help someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, same issue but due to netrc file. Python requests library decided to override the Authorization header if a netrc matching entry is found.
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#netrc-authentication