# Curl works but python requests doesn't

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, docker, curl

When I do curl, I get a response:

```
root@3d7044bac92f:/home/app/tmp# curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET https://github.com/timeline.json -k 

{"message":"Hello there, wayfaring stranger. If you\u2019re reading this then you probably didn\u2019t see our blog post a couple of years back announcing that this API would go away: http://git.io/17AROg Fear not, you should be able to get what you need from the shiny new Events API instead.","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events"}
```

However, when I do python requests to the same URL I get a status 410.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
}

r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
print r.json

root@3d7044bac92f:/home/app/tmp# python rest.py 
<bound method Response.json of <Response [410]>>
```

What gives?

The host is a standard Ubuntu docker image and only installed Curl and some python modules. Python -V is 2.7

Note: I looked at this question but I can't telnet into above server so that solution doesn't apply to me:
[Curl works but not Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970333/curl-works-but-not-python-requests)

Comment: can you `print r.text` instead?

Comment: The curl receives  a 410 response as well. `curl -i` or `curl -v` will show you the response headers.

Answer (score 3):

You've made at least two errors in your program.

1) You haven't specified the `data=` or `headers` parameters to the `requests.get()` call. Try this:

```
 r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json', data=data, headers=headers)
```

2) `.json` is a method, not a data attribute of the response object. As a method, it must be called in order to be effective. Try this:

```
print r.json()
```

Comment: The json() is it. Thanks!