# Why does the following curl works but equivalent python code does not?

Tags: api, web-scraping, curl, python-requests

The following curl is working:

```
curl --location 'https://www.lowes.com/rnr/r/get-by-product/50413062/pdp/prod?sortMethod=SubmissionTime&sortDirection=desc&offset=0' \
--header 'authority: www.lowes.com' \
--header 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
--header 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,ur;q=0.6,pa;q=0.5,es;q=0.4' \
--header 'dnt: 1' \
--header 'referer: https://www.lowes.com/pd/KitchenAid-25-8-cu-ft-5-Door-French-Door-Refrigerator-with-Ice-Maker-Stainless-Steel/50413062' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
--header 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
--header 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
--header 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
--header 'Cookie: EPID=OGFhNmEzMWItMTI5Mi00OTk5LWE0MDMtNDE0M2FjZWVhMGYw; _abck=F42771C150B4C119EC8B175032CA9585~-1~YAAQl24/Fxke7uWGAQAA2GM8+wnNceF82+OD7MYSY54sfGjY6sI9gk/3TA4PXZJET2G+qbMoKQblP1E6vLRIN9mNrI7hUixTfWSLLY3M6mtGEAJVhM4QZInOEUYep02CB7YspAAj33IAsz1CjJ6CTVGMkBHaD3xcYTERPO/ciOfY+BBBDxr+3P5xaqF3UYfPCKt7hKF9Mma2Ov/Q3adCanBW3jFQ3pSfaUZJkoJwqLdcydDMT0X/OUfPEBD5o6DlFFeLGNISFMr9GWt3LEI1WgtkQ8JuCEfaPx6wB0OGXt3CT3rSv3FJWOpqQdDkiEld74IHsPhXkxrfD1ujjX6Mhvioab5tcf49CdmtqD9ew+XOjNZGg+fvIx4/qCDzlcTJAQIjOvdiMhowip38mm9gkgCbhh808pb5y3J+mQ==~-1~-1~-1; bm_sz=1A8431CC8D5EB5603F27267A256FB757~YAAQl24/Fxoe7uWGAQAA2GM8+xNq6E5oqP5QkZ1IFVKNETajEDxDQPsGYZPLcy71Ye8/DDeGwZlryGa+D3p18VEw6uIkOsFnLSUbVX50hwSaGaj+KMNvfjWBiRvNSsrk+OFSTKGWpB6e0cbbctbqDFEw1YJDCK5GdAw3ZKSNBxaUnRLQFoFlFpdzBe26MQo6CkIeMx9mq3oNnaajwjEwSyOzbGclasWViYeL0nzNgiKXvfD+MEFOvbtwU/+9ymXhAJUiLUPBQdyCF6aVWspjx9SNaEGR+iuu7jBUjnDcldwGnQ==~3355461~4539959; dbidv2=8aa6a31b-1292-4999-a403-4143aceea0f0; akaalb_prod_dual=1679338684~op=PROD_GCP_EAST_CTRL_DFLT:PROD_DEFAULT_CTRL|~rv=31~m=PROD_DEFAULT_CTRL:0|~os=352fb8a62db4e37e16b221fb4cefd635~id=ece72cac85177577cc3b22d07a88c063; region=central'
```

But the following python code which does the same thing is not working

```
import requests

url = "https://www.lowes.com/rnr/r/get-by-product/50413062/pdp/prod?sortMethod=SubmissionTime&sortDirection=desc&offset=0"

payload={}
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.lowes.com',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,ur;q=0.6,pa;q=0.5,es;q=0.4',
  'dnt': '1',
  'referer': 'https://www.lowes.com/pd/KitchenAid-25-8-cu-ft-5-Door-French-Door-Refrigerator-with-Ice-Maker-Stainless-Steel/50413062',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'Cookie': 'EPID=OGFhNmEzMWItMTI5Mi00OTk5LWE0MDMtNDE0M2FjZWVhMGYw; _abck=F42771C150B4C119EC8B175032CA9585~-1~YAAQl24/Fxke7uWGAQAA2GM8+wnNceF82+OD7MYSY54sfGjY6sI9gk/3TA4PXZJET2G+qbMoKQblP1E6vLRIN9mNrI7hUixTfWSLLY3M6mtGEAJVhM4QZInOEUYep02CB7YspAAj33IAsz1CjJ6CTVGMkBHaD3xcYTERPO/ciOfY+BBBDxr+3P5xaqF3UYfPCKt7hKF9Mma2Ov/Q3adCanBW3jFQ3pSfaUZJkoJwqLdcydDMT0X/OUfPEBD5o6DlFFeLGNISFMr9GWt3LEI1WgtkQ8JuCEfaPx6wB0OGXt3CT3rSv3FJWOpqQdDkiEld74IHsPhXkxrfD1ujjX6Mhvioab5tcf49CdmtqD9ew+XOjNZGg+fvIx4/qCDzlcTJAQIjOvdiMhowip38mm9gkgCbhh808pb5y3J+mQ==~-1~-1~-1; bm_sz=1A8431CC8D5EB5603F27267A256FB757~YAAQl24/Fxoe7uWGAQAA2GM8+xNq6E5oqP5QkZ1IFVKNETajEDxDQPsGYZPLcy71Ye8/DDeGwZlryGa+D3p18VEw6uIkOsFnLSUbVX50hwSaGaj+KMNvfjWBiRvNSsrk+OFSTKGWpB6e0cbbctbqDFEw1YJDCK5GdAw3ZKSNBxaUnRLQFoFlFpdzBe26MQo6CkIeMx9mq3oNnaajwjEwSyOzbGclasWViYeL0nzNgiKXvfD+MEFOvbtwU/+9ymXhAJUiLUPBQdyCF6aVWspjx9SNaEGR+iuu7jBUjnDcldwGnQ==~3355461~4539959; dbidv2=8aa6a31b-1292-4999-a403-4143aceea0f0; akaalb_prod_dual=1679338684~op=PROD_GCP_EAST_CTRL_DFLT:PROD_DEFAULT_CTRL|~rv=31~m=PROD_DEFAULT_CTRL:0|~os=352fb8a62db4e37e16b221fb4cefd635~id=ece72cac85177577cc3b22d07a88c063; region=central'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I am getting a valid json as response while excuting the curl.
But getting blocked while using the python code. The response of the python code is the following.

```
'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;lowes&#46;com&#47;rnr&#47;r&#47;get&#45;by&#45;product&#47;5013699701&#47;pdp&#47;prod&#63;" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;b56e3f17&#46;1679223477&#46;1d4c5ef7\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
```

what can I do in python code to get it working.

I more thing I want to add. The above curl will stop working if chrome version is changed to 110 or 108 in user-agents.

HELP! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not well versed with curl, is there a way to check the precise HTTP request curl is sending?

Comment: I am not aware of that.

Comment: but one trick I know is that replace url of curl with this site http://www.xhaus.com/headers . and you might get some useful information.

Comment: Try this. In your python script, remove the `cookie` header and add `"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"`. And use `requests.get(url, headers)`

Comment: I was able to get it working myself. check my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75784845/8087010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem myself. As it turns out lowes is using ssl version TLS 1.3 (Check yourself on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.lowes.com)

So I made python requests library to use TLS 1.3 and then I got the valid response.

Used the following code to change the ssl version in requests.

```py
import requests
import ssl
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context

class CustomSSLAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    CIPHERS = (
        'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:'
        'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:'
        'TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:'
        'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:'
        'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:'
        'ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:'
    )

    def create_ssl_context(self):
        ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
        ctx.set_ciphers(self.CIPHERS)
        ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2
        return ctx

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT,
            ssl_context=self.create_ssl_context(),
        )

url = 'https://www.lowes.com/rnr/r/get-by-product/50413062/pdp/prod?sortMethod=SubmissionTime&sortDirection=desc&offset=0'
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,ur;q=0.6,pa;q=0.5,es;q=0.4',
    'dnt': '1',
    'referer': 'https://www.lowes.com/pd/KitchenAid-25-8-cu-ft-5-Door-French-Door-Refrigerator-with-Ice-Maker-Stainless-Steel/50413062',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', CustomSSLAdapter())

response = session.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: This is interesting. How'd you figure it out? And why did I not have to do this? I know very little about how networking works, so I'm just curious.

Comment: Wouldn't have been able to do it without chatgpt-4. It gave me idea and the code.

Comment: I am still wondering why you didnt have to it. The request also work for me if I am using http library. it only does't work in requests. requests is built upon http. Why operating system are you using? and which requests version?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and requests==2.28.2